# Trying to find the comic this page featuring Wonder Woman, the Atom, and Batman was taken from

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics

The artwork looks distinct. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Could you post a link to the web page where you found this image? It might not help, but you never know. If nothing else, it's nice to be reassured that we're not missing out on potential clues.

Comment: https://pin.it/20psnAF

Comment: This is her late 1970s outfit, I think; http://carolastrickland.com/comics/wwcentral/costume_indices/wwcost4.html

Comment: The costumes and artwork are old-fashioned, but the coloring is modern. So either a recolored reprint or a retro comic. I am willing to bet the latter.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen - I'm often surprised at the scan quality you find when people have access to the original prints

Comment: @Valorum: It's not the scan quality, but the coloring style. The soft tones, esp. in the background, are not something you could do with the old four-color hans seperation technique. It is obviously computer coloration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is from [*DC Comics Presents: Justice League of America Vol. 2* Issue 1](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/DC_Comics_Presents:_Justice_League_of_America_Vol_2_1).

[image: Page 1 from the scan in question] [image: Page 2 from the scan in question]

Comment: I've edited the images so they're rendered smaller (click through is still full sized) for better readability and removed the cover image as it wasn't really necessary and just noise. I also formatted the link like `[link text](link)` so it renders nicer. If you disagree with any of these changes though feel free to [edit] this yourself or roll back my changes completely! Also nice find, welcome to the site!

Answer (score 4):

This is [DC Comics Presents Vol. 2 (2004) Justice League of America Vol 2 1](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/DC_Comics_Presents:_Justice_League_of_America_Vol_2_1#Synopsis_for_.22Secret_Behind_the_Stolen_Super-Weapons.22), specifically the story *'Secret Behind the Stolen Super-Weapons'*.

> The Flash becomes bold and informs the now giant editor that he works
> for them. Julie responds by sending him flying out the window. The
> Flash bounces like a pinball around the city before Wonder Woman goes
> to help him. **Julie manipulates her magic lasso and instead of helping
> the Flash he turns the Amazon into a human yo-yo.** The Atom tries to
> save his teammate, but Julie uses the Atom's powers against him and
> sends the tiny hero to Omaha via the telephone.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Makes slightly more sense with context...